# Blender particle computations don't get updated

Tags: animation, particles

It seems in latest Blender versions it's common that Blender will precompute particle transforms, but when you change some setting, it won't get recalculated and the old animation will play. For example, changing the normal of the particle won't change anything, enabling/disabling physics won't change anything.

Is this a known bug and is there a way to force Blender to redo the calculations? Right now my only option has been remaking the particle system from scratch.

While there is a "Free All Bakes" option for Particles, it doesn't always seem to work, especially with "Keyed" mode.

Comment: At the Particles > Cache settings, have you tried "Free All Bakes" to reset the particles Cache? Then press "Bake All Dynamics" to recalculate...

Comment: Seems to be missing when in Keyed particle mode. That, or it doesn't actually clear the cache.

Comment: I see now. Uhm maybe if you emty your tmp folder the actual cache gets deleted (if there is any in keyed mode).

Comment: tmp folder? As in C:\\tmp, the default folder frames are saved in? Because there is no file in there.